# Finding out specific processes that are running php commands shown in 'top -i'

Tags: command-line, php, process, top

I have been scouring the forums to find the next step in analysing what process specifically is requesting the usage of a php command shown when running the `top -i` in an Ubuntu 20.04 server cli.

After SSH'ing into a server that is reporting 100% CPU usage, I can see:

| PID | USER | PR | NI | VIRT | RES | SHR | S | %CPU | %MEM | TIME+ | COMMAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18266 | mysql | 20 | 0 | 1354720 | 496864 | 38872 | S | 45.1 | 24.5 | 7:01.28 | mysqld |
| 17012 | hills | 20 | 0 | 337656 | 67748 | 43384 | R | 14.4 | 3.3 | 0:45.32 | php-fpm8.0 |
| 17017 | hills | 20 | 0 | 339840 | 66492 | 40040 | R | 12.7 | 3.3 | 0:40.82 | php-fpm8.0 |
| 13618 | hills | 20 | 0 | 341960 | 69600 | 41128 | R | 12.4 | 3.4 | 1:23.47 | php-fpm8.0 |
| 13612 | hills | 20 | 0 | 340016 | 67796 | 41256 | S | 11.8 | 3.3 | 1:26.96 | php-fpm8.0 |

The obvious is that the mysqld is requesting a lot from the CPU. I can figure out what specifically is being ran that is costing so much memory within the mysqld command by finding its process ID `pidstat -t -p {PID} 1` collecting its {TID} signing into mysql `mysql -u root -p` then selecting that process with a select query `select * from performance_schema.threads where THREAD_OS_ID = {TID} \G`.

I am wondering if there is an equivalent that will show me what specifically is requesting each of the php-fpm8.0 commands running that are shown in the list above?

Comment: sounds like a PHP question, not Ubuntu. Perhaps phmypadmin https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ would help you. I know it's a GUI tool, but it may help you figure out which queries or processes consume the memory in its dashboards.

Comment: You might be correct, @mondotofu. I will leave this here just in case as I do see some overlap, but it is regarding the PHP processes!

Comment: Another option in Ubuntu is the **pstree** command.

Comment: @mondotofu, this is a good idea, however if I use pstree {ONE_OF_THE_PIDs_IN_top -i_LIST} it simply returns php-fpm8.0 which doesn't get me much further, unless you know of an option I need to add to show the full tree?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps a combination of

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

and

```
pstree -a -l -h -p  {ONE_OF_THE_PIDs}
```

would help.
I'm not running php, but I am running postgres. Here's a sample output for you.

```
steve@AntHill2:~$ ps -ef | grep post
postgres    1115       1  0 08:39 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
postgres    1153    1115  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 12/main: checkpointer   
postgres    1154    1115  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 12/main: background writer   
postgres    1155    1115  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 12/main: walwriter   
postgres    1156    1115  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 12/main: autovacuum launcher   
postgres    1157    1115  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 12/main: stats collector   
postgres    1158    1115  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 12/main: logical replication launcher   
steve      17723   17577  0 20:10 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto post
steve@AntHill2:~$ pstree -a -l -h -p  1115
postgres,1115 -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
  ├─postgres,1153
  ├─postgres,1154
  ├─postgres,1155
  ├─postgres,1156
  ├─postgres,1157
  └─postgres,1158
```

If this does not help, try the arguments for pstree. If still no luck, then I recommend phpadmin or look in the php Stack Exchange forum.

Comment: again helpful answer! I think this has indirectly highlighted it is the pools that are appearing as duplicate entries for php-fpm8.0